# jquery.ui.autocomplete not hitting stored procedure

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following function that should return values based either on a Last Name or ID that is entered into a text box. It is not working on my base page which has several layers of tabs, and the autocomplete is located in one of the sub-tabs. So I cut it out a tried the function on a new page and was able to get my results. So might it be that the level of tabs has anything to do with it.
On the text field I have an onfocus = FillStaff() in both the test page and the base page, but it only goes into this function on the test page and not the tabbed page.

```
function FillStaff() {
if ($("#txtSearchCriteria").val() == '') {
    $("#txtSearchCriteria").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                delay: 250,
                url: 'wsCourse.asmx/GetStaffList1',
                data: "{'Param1':'" + $('#hdfldUser').val() + "', 'Param2':'" + request.term.replace(/'/g, "\&apos") + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('|')[0],
                            val: item.split('|')[1]
                        }   // end of return
                    }))    // end of response
                }   // end of success
            });      // end of ajax
        },    // end of source
        select: function (e, i) {
            $('#hdfldStaffID').val(i.item.val);
        }, // end of select
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(event.target).val('');
            }
        },
        minLength: 3
    })    // end of txtSearchCriteria.autocomplete
  }
}    // end of FillStaff
```

Thanks for your help.

```
    <div id="courseButtons" >
    <button id="btnAddNewCourse" type="button" class="button" >Add New Course</button> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblNameSearch" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="Search by Last Name or PIC:"></asp:Label>
    <input id="txtSearchCriteria" type="text" onclick="javascript: this.select();" onfocus="FillStaff()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see more code to debug this. You said that the function works on your test page, which means, theoretically, that there is nothing wrong with the function you posted, but rather with other code elsewhere that you did not post.

Comment: you need to put that in your original question, in a code block, so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a variable that was not declared. I'm sorry I wasted your time.